Why are there still coax shield currents in this system?
I have the following system set up in the lab:

An RF signal generator feeds 2 meters of RG-178 coax, this coax connects through a 1:1 balun (a "voltage balun" configuration) and connects to around 1.5 meters of 300 ohm twin lead, terminated in 300R. The balun is a Mini-Circuits T1-1T. The cables are draped in free space, as far as I could manage from nearby metal, around waist height.
I am able to measure antenna mode (common mode) currents on both the coax and the twin lead by measuring the induced current on a loop encircling the transmission line. I have a couple spectrum analyzers, a Rogowski coil (good to 30 MHz), and a clip-on ferrite bead with a dozen turns of wire. The ferrite bead is most sensitive and works to a couple hundred MHz for qualitative measurements.
Here is what I've observed:

When the coax is disconnected from the balun and twin lead, its antenna mode currents disappear, regardless of the load (open, short, 50 ohm).
When the coax connects to the balun and twin lead, both transmission lines show strong antenna mode currents, which fall off as frequency drops below 10 MHz.
The antenna mode currents form standing waves with a propagation velocity equal to free space \$c\$, based on the frequency and separation between nodes.
Rotating the balun ("current balun" configuration) does not affect the results at all.


I experimented with frequencies from 10 MHz through 300 MHz (note that the T1:1T balun is only spec'd to 200 MHz, additional IL and poor RL occur outside that range).
My question: Why do I still get common mode/antenna mode currents on the coax in these configurations? (And what can I do to fix the imbalance difference?)

Edit 1: I also tried a 1:4 (Pri:Sec) balun, the Mini-Circuits ADT4-6T. This helps the impedance match, which I verified with a VNA across the whole cable. Return loss is good. Even still, the shield currents measured were not significantly changed. This was in the voltage balun configuration.

The right part of the coax 50 Ohm is "wired" only to the transformer ... so you get what you observed ... current in the shield.

Could you explain that a bit further? How does connecting coax only to a balun cause common mode?

They don't give much info in the datasheet unfortunately, regarding isolation and balance. Have you tried grounding the secondary center tap?

@TimWilliams grounding the center tap should work, though I'm not sure which ground I would connect it to in this case. Mini-Circuits provides an s2p file for the balun, maybe that can provide some insights? Continuing experimenting today

Well, to ground of course; coax shield being the ground most local to the transformer.  An s2p file is 2 ports, not the 4 ports that a complete description of the component would require, so no more help there I suspect. The best answer to this may be your own: perhaps you can set up a jig to quantify the transformer's own common-mode performance and report back here?

Oops, I was mistaken, they actually provide an s4p file. I took some measurements of the primary to secondary capacitance, came to about 4pF (3.9-4.2pF), then compared with the s-parameters from Mini-Circuits in qucs, which shows the same, so that's encouraging. Looks like I can follow this track and get some insight.


An RF signal generator feeds 2 meters of RG-178 coax, this coax connects through a 1:1 balun

If it is indeed the case that you have a 50 \$\Omega\$ coax connected through a 1:1 balun to a 300 \$\Omega\$ twin-lead, then your transmission lines is not properly terminated. The 50 \$\Omega\$ line sees a 300 \$\Omega\$ termination, and your 300 \$\Omega\$ transmission line sees a 50 \$\Omega\$ termination. This will result in standing waves in your transmission line.
To properly connect a 50 \$\Omega\$ line to a 300 \$\Omega\$ line, you need a transformer with an approximately \$\sqrt{300/50}\approx2.45\$ transformation ratio. A 9:4 transformer has a 2.25 ratio, and in most cases would be adequate, but not perfect.

Rotating the balun ("current balun" configuration) does not affect the results at all.

It wouldn't because you are still connecting a 50 \$\Omega\$ transmission line to a 300 \$\Omega\$ transmission line. You will therefore get standing waves.

A 9:4 transformer has a 2.25 ratio 5:2 is closer to 6^.5.

Thanks, a couple quibbles though: First, standing waves are not the same as shield currents. The VSWR is not an indication of common mode currents, because those standing waves are still differential mode. Second, since the 300 ohm line is terminated in 300 ohms, there are no reflections on the twin lead, so the reverse match doesn't matter, and the only important mismatch is on the transition from coax into twin lead. That is, only the coax has standing waves. Doesn't change the common mode though. I found my answer later, will post one here if I get the chance.

Via skin effect.  When you connect the braid to a load, you have three arms for current to flow.  The center conductor, the inside of the braid and a return component (CM) on the outside of the braid back to the signal ground.
A properly wound and ideal balun or unun, will attenuate CM current but not eliminate it completely.  That requires a line choke to keep it from returning to the generator.
Research the differences between voltage and current baluns. A voltage balun wants to force both legs to the same potential (Ruthruff) and a current the same with current (Guanella). Hope this helps. OwenDuffy.net has a slew of articles on demystifying baluns. He's a proponent of autotransformers for simplicity, customization and performance.
